# Creality Ender 3 v2 Neo bed leveling doesn't seem to work

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

I purchased an Ender 3 v2 Neo a few days ago, but every time I try to do the bed leveling it is either too close and the nozzle touches the bed (even though it was fine while leveling) or just completely misses it and travels a few mm above it.
I tried really thin paper, regular A4 but every time I start a test print (the one that prints a little circle on the corners and in the middle) it's just the worst possible outcome every time.

Tried following multiple YouTube videos step by step but none seem to help.

I made sure that the nozzle wasn't too close to the bed, but no.

Not sure if it's a problem but I also had to use the offset feature to get close enough.

What should I do/change?

Comment: I am having the same issue... Although I'm at the part where I'm not sure if I'm the problem or the printer. Gonna start with a detailed manual leveling and messing with the tensions